# Grouping and counting issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
Id,Code, (some more columns)
1, c
1, a
1, b
1, b
1, b
2, a -- the desired row
3, b
3, c
3, a
3, a
```

I want to get one Id (or all) which have only been associated with 'a' and not 'b' and 'c'. How do I do this ?

What i tried just now:

```
select *
from
(
select Id, count(case when Code='a' then 0 else 1 end) c
from tbl
group by Id
)
where c = 0
```

Why does this not work ?

Comment: Show your desired output please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the list of Id values which are associated only with codes of `'a'`.

```
select Id
from tbl
group by Id
having max(case when Code='a' then 0 else 1 end) = 0
```

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b57c/1) for a live demo.

Comment: My code column is actually integers. I changed max to count and your answer did not work for me. Please see my updated question as well. Sorry for the confusion. I only changed the column to make it easy to read. thanks.

Comment: If code is integer, you just need to change the `Code='a'` bit to `Code=123` or whatever your target code is. Don't change `max` to `count`.

Comment: thanks. please see my new query and tell me my mistake. your query works for me.

Comment: `count` just counts the number of results, including zeroes. I think you meant `sum`. `max` would also work.

Comment: oh ok. got it. When count finds, say id = 2, code = a, we get count(0), i.e count zero once. So, every time count encounters a 2,0, it counts zero once.